# How to create a JobObject with JOB_OBJECT_SECURITY_ONLY_TOKEN security limitation?

Tags: c, windows

Could someone please help me? I'm trying to create a jobobject with `JOB_OBJECT_SECURITY_ONLY_TOKEN` but `SetInformationJobObject` always fails with error code 6 ( Invalid handle ). 
Here is my code:

```
HANDLE Job( CreateJobObject( NULL, NULL ) );
if( !Job )
{
    wprintf( L"Could not create job object, error %d\n", GetLastError() );
    return 1;
}

JOBOBJECT_SECURITY_LIMIT_INFORMATION SecLimit = { 0 };
SecLimit.SecurityLimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_SECURITY_ONLY_TOKEN;

if ( !SetInformationJobObject( Job, JobObjectSecurityLimitInformation, &SecLimit, sizeof( SecLimit ) ) )
{
    wprintf( L"Could not associate job with IO completion port, error %d\n", GetLastError() );
    return 1;
}
```

I am trying to run this app on XP!
Thanks!

Comment: Check the MSDN article: `This flag is not supported`

Comment: I found that too. But acording to this article http://blog.yezhucn.com/dllproc/assignprocesstojobobject.htm a jobobject requires the JOB_OBJECT_SECURITY_ONLY_TOKEN security limitation, so do i grant it?

Comment: @HansPassant: it's still supported for XP, so this isn't the OPs problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set `SecLimit.JobToken` to a valid handle to a restricted token.  That's why you're getting an invalid handle error.  If you use the `JOB_OBJECT_SECURITY_ONLY_TOKEN` flag, `SecLimit.JobToken` is mandatory.

Unless there is some particular reason why you need to force processes in the job to use a restricted token, don't use the JOB_OBJECT_SECURITY_ONLY_TOKEN flag.

Note that the article you reference does not in fact say that this flag is required.  It only says that *if* you use this flag the process must be created suspended in order to assign it to the job object.

Comment: The reason why i want to use the JOB_OBJECT_SECURITY_ONLY_TOKEN flag is, that AssignProcessToJobObject fails with Access Denied on Windows XP SP3 machines( on Windows 7 it works fine). Unfortunately i didn't find any reference or working code to see what am i doing wrong, so i thought maybe this solution could work. Please see my other question, maybe you can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449531/why-does-assignprocesstojobobject-fail-on-xp-with-error-access-denied Thans in advance!