# How to detach a process from a JobObject

Tags: c, windows

Is there a way to detach a process, from a JobObject? 
My problem is, that if i create a  new process with RunAs, like cmd.exe, then it will be assigned to a JobObject automatically. And if I want to run my application from this cmd it will also be assigned to this jobobject. The problem starts here, because my application would create a new jobobject and create a new process and then assign it to my new JobObject, but it can't associate, because the first cmd started with runas, is already assigned to a jobobject, and so the new process what I created is also assigned to this jobobject.

So my question is, how can I detach the first cmd from the jobobject which will be automatically created, or how else can I solve this problem?

Comment: Check out `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` flag (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But I don't know whether RunAs uses job object as a security measure. If it does, it will have `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK` disabled and the flag won't work.

Comment: Also, Windows 8 seems to support nested jobs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so if you can have your app "Windows 8 only"... :)

Comment: @atzz: Unfortunately, my app has to run under XP and Windows 7 too, so Windows 8 is not option :)

Comment: @atzz: I think RunAs uses a job object, because if you open a cmd with runas, it is already associated to a job. And this is my problem :(

Comment: You cannot disassociate an existing process from a job. But if `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` flag works under RunAs, you can create a child process with this flag, and the child will be free from the job. The question is whether RunAs allows the use of this flag. If it doesn't set `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK` when starting `cmd`, the flag won't work.

Comment: I try to start a new process from cmd which i opened with runas, but i always get access denied. CreateProcessW( NULL, CommandLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB, NULL, NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInformation ) I have to search a little, what could be the problem

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using runas, consider running the parent application as the standard user and using [`CreateProcessWithLogonW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to elevate.

Alternatively, you could use [`psexec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) which, although designed for executing commands remotely, can often be useful to escape your current context on the local computer.  You could either use psexec as an alternative to runas:

```
psexec -i \\%COMPUTERNAME% -u adminuser cmd.exe
```

(you will be prompted for the password) or you could use runas and then

```
psexec -s -i \\%COMPUTERNAME% parent.exe
```

to run `parent.exe` in local system context.  This will escape the existing job object, because the new process is launched from a system service.

Note that using `psexec` with the `-i` flag is trickier in Vista and later because it uses multiple terminal server sessions more extensively; in that scenario you're probably better off sticking with runas.  Luckily your problem only applies to XP. :-)

Comment: Future readers should also see this question, which offers another approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490055/how-to-get-a-handle-to-a-jobobject-without-knowing-its-name